# Error 500 when Debug off on both local and Heroku with Whitenoise

Tags: python, django, heroku, whitenoise

I'm having alot of trouble either understanding how to properly host my static files on both local and heroku. Currently when Debug is turned off, I get an error 500- otherwise it works fine.

I've read quite a few SO posts but so far, no solution has helped. I've also tried to host staticfiles on AWS, but this has still not helped.

**Edit**
I currently get a 500 error on any page but the admin console.

Error from django server:

```
[27/Nov/2019 13:36:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 9061
```

Error from web console:

```
Failed to load resource: localhost1/: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Below is my code:

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_select2',
    'masterform',
    'tempus_dominus',
    'team',
    'sms',
    'opportunities',
    "rest_framework",
    'import_export',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)



STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "live-static", "static-root")
```

urls.py

```
from django.views.static import serve
from bdsurveyapp import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url('', include('opportunities.urls')),
    url(r'^sms/', include('sms.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url(r'^dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='pages/login.html'), name="login"),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='pages/logout.html'), name="logout"),
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

partial base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static  %}

<head>
  {{ form.media.css }}

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="{% static 'img/apple-touch-icon.png' %}">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="{% static 'img/favicon-32x32.png' %}">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{% static 'img/favicon-16x16.png' %}">

  <link rel="manifest" href="{% static 'img/site.webmanifest' %}">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="{% static 'img/safari-pinned-tab.svg' %}" color="#5bbad5">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
```

Comment: Where do you get a 500? Show the error, the URL you used, and the relevant log entry.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks for the comment- i've just added those details.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I found that when I commented out `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` my issues were fixed.